# Geodesic equation for surface of sphere

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, calculus-of-variations

One of the standard problems of calculus of variations is showing that geodesics on the surface of the sphere are great circles.

But I don't understand the equation. The equation for great circle path is derived to be:

$$ a\cos(\phi-\phi_0) = \cot(\theta)$$
Where $\phi_0$ and $a$ are constants of integration, and everything else has a standard meaning of spherical geometry.

This equation should describe a great circle path, so lets choose one in equatorial plane $\theta=\pi/2$, gives gives:
$$a\cos(\phi-\phi_0)=0$$

But this is no equation of the circle, this is just set of 2 points where $\phi-\phi_0=\pi/2, 3\pi/2$.

Comment: Can you tell us how you get the first equation?

Comment: Equation is obtained here: http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/reh10/lectures/nst-mmii-handout2.pdf

Comment: From your source, it seems that $\phi$ is a function of $\theta$. I don't see why you can set it to be a fixed number.

Comment: Note that from the derivation, $\phi$ is assumed to be a function of $\theta$. In particular, this parametrization does not describe any great circle which corresponds to a fixed $\theta$.

Comment: Then what does is equation even means? There should be a way of obtaining a great circle for every $\theta$.

Comment: It is **not** for each $\theta$, one get a great circle. Instead, it should be "for each $\theta$, I obtain a $\phi$, and the set containing all these $(\theta, \phi)$ gives me all the point in a fixed great circle. If you want another great circle, alter the value $a$. Different $a$ corresponds to different great circle.

Comment: One of the great circles would be a set of points $(0, \phi)$ for every $\phi$, but I just don't see how one could obtain it. Unless $\theta$ does not correspond to a physical latitude coordinate, but is somehow mathematical parameterization?

Comment: The great circle you described cannot be parametrized as $\phi = \phi(\theta)$. So the method in your note cannot be used to find all the great circle. The method can find only those not passing through the north pole $(0,0,1)$.

Comment: Thanks for the help, if you could write an answer I will mark it as answered.